# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'created_date', table 'WebApp.dbo.Inventories';

Tags: database, model, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-web-api2

I created a model `BaseModel` to inherit these 2 properties `date_created` and `date_modified` to all models in my database to keep a record when a record is created and when a record is modified.

I added the `?` operator for these properties to accept null values ​​as shown below:

Base model:

```cs
namespace API.Models
{
    public class BaseModel
    {
        public BaseModel()
        {
            created_date = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public DateTime? created_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Inventories** table:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace API.Models
{
    public class Inventory : BaseModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int inventory_id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es obligatorio"), StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "{0} la longitud debe estar entre {2} y {1}.", MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string? location { get; set; }
        public bool? status { get; set; }

        public List<Asset> assets { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Asset** table:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace API.Models
{
    public class Asset : BaseModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int asset_id { get; set; }
        public int? code { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es obligatorio"), StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "{0} la longitud debe estar entre {2} y {1}.", MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string? name { get; set; }
        public int iventory_id { get; set; }
        public Inventory inventory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I add the migrations

```
dotnet ef migrations add v15
```

and apply the migrations

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'created_date', table 'WebApp.dbo.Iventories'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
> The statement has been terminated

I don't understand why I am getting this error.

When I add `?` operator should the database not accept null values​​?

Comment: I build one project with these items, But don't have any Errors after the Update Database.  Can I see your Asset Entity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use these

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public BaseModel()
    {
        created_date = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? created_date { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? modified_date { get; set; }

}
```

or

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public BaseModel()
    {
        created_date = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Nullable<DateTime> created_date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> modified_date { get; set; }

}
```

[I uplaod sample code in git, just change ConnectionString](https://github.com/thisisnabi/Stackoverflow-Helps/tree/master/EF-InsertNullToDataTime)